# Rails - Checking Attributes Through Another Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a three models, Organizations, Jobs, and Users. See the relations below:

User.rb

```
has_many :organizations, :through => :jobs
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
```

Organization.rb

```
has_many :users, :through => :jobs
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
```

Job.rb

```
belongs_to :organization, :foreign_key => :organization_id
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
```

So as you can see a Job relates to an Organization and a User. Every job has a role attached to it, being either, regular, admin or management. What I am trying to do is see if the `current_user` is an admin or manager for the organization **in the view.** If they have a job within an organization that has the role management then they would be a manager, etc.

What I have been able to is query for the organizations a user manages using:

```
includes(:jobs).where(jobs: { :user_id => current_user.id, :role => ["management", "admin"] }
```

But how can I, given an organization object, check in the view if the user is a manager or admin?

i.e. `if current_user.organization.admin?`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from your query you can use something like this in your view:

```
<% @organizations.each do |organization| %>
  <% if organization.jobs.any? { |job| job.role == "manager" } %>
    <%= # do something  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```